# Changing Facebook application default visibility

Tags: facebook, visibility

I'm developing a mobile app using a few facebook features (mostly Login and Feed).
The application connects people who are already friends on facebook, and since they used the fblogin, I can get the *"user's friends also using the app"* list with a FQL query.

Now, if a user has the app visibility set to "only me", he won't show show up to his friends with a fql query or a getAppUsers call, wich seems quite logical.

This is a problem since every user installing the app has it set to "**only me**" by default in the Application Center.

In the "permissions" settings of the app's config , the "*Default Activity Privacy*" is set to "**friends**" and the scope is [email, user_photos, user_birthday]; but it doesn't really seems to matter. I have this problem with my own account (ie, remove & reinstall the app -> only me) and tests accounts.
The app is not in sandbox, and i have ran out of email aliases (and time) trying to figure this out.

Is there a way to set the app's default visibility or am i missing something obvious ?

Am I wrong about how i should handle this (should i simply get the user's friendlist and check it against the other members' to find out relationships and isn't it circumventing facebook policies ?) ?